# Forcing updates to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Our road is sometimes (cannot reproduce now) marked with red stripes on Google maps. Not sure what that means, but at least it does not navigate to this road.

This means that Google Maps leads people to the nearest freeway, and indicates they have arrived when they are on the freeway adjacent to our house. This is both annoying and dangerous in cases where people try to stop or such.

I have tried submitting map changes many times, during the previous 5 years or so, but nothing is happening. I am unable to find somebody to contact in this regard, and very frustrated that this can apparently not be fixed.

Any ideas what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Where have you tried submitting map changes to?

Comment: Maybe updating as many other road base (OpenStreetMap, Here, TomTom, waze...) as you can may help Google maps to realize something is wrong and at least will direct all who use these service the right way (not everybody use Google map)

Answer (score 2):

As a private company working on their own private database there is no way to force Google to do anything.

But there are way to make you voice heard more.

One way is to join the Local Guides program: https://maps.google.com/localguides

This allows you to accrue points by reviewing and submitting photos and locations. This builds trust with Google.

You can also submit correction to other locations. If there are deemed correct that will also build your reputation with Google.

Currently if you are just correcting one road consistently it might look like you're trying to sabotage the map.

My reviews of Google locations are being accepted usually within a day.

An alternative would be to use OpenStreetMap. Which you could force to update.